# In C# can we check if a duplicate value is entered

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a grid view where I'm trying to insert a new value. Before doing an insert need to check if the value entered already exists in DB (cannot be duplicate). 
The column that needs to be checked for duplicate is of type varchar which can accept maximum characters in a string (it can have spaces and can also have other special characters - it is basically a sentence). 
E.g.  Insert specific job-related impacts: (for example, impacts to customer or client service)
We cannot make this column unique in SQL server as it is declared as varchar(max).
Can we perform a check for a large string like this from C#?

Comment: You could do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TheTable WHERE TheField=@MyUniqueValue` and check to see if you get a result >0 before inserting.  The problem is that `VARCHAR(MAX) can't be indexed, so it could potentially be very slow

Comment: I tried this approach earlier to get a count of rows. But even though the entered matches the count is always '0' and hence it is inserting the record.

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me.  Can you show us the code you were using?

Comment: Can you redefine this field to not be `varchar(max)`? Be realistic here - are you ever going to *need* 2GB of text in this field? How much are you storing there today? I bet you aren't even going over 4000 characters.

Comment: I combined two stored proc earlier where I was passing the input parameter as @Name varchar(30). I created a new SP where I defined input parameter as max and it worked. Prompt varchar(max) = Null,
 Row_Count int output

Comment: My question here is: it is possible to check for a large string with spaces in between to see if it is a duplicate value that is entered? E.g. Insert specific performance concern, for example, production, quality, etc.:  The string need not be just a single word separated by underscore or any other special character to do a comparison and get a row count. E.g:  Insert_specific_performance_concern,_for_example,_production,_quality_,etc.:

Comment: Are you creating a single user system? If not, no amount of pre-checking can answer the question "will this value exist in the database *at the time I attempt an `INSERT`*?"

Answer (score 0):

The primary concept is as follows:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int columnToCheck = 0;//The index of the property/field/column you want to check
        if (e.ColumnIndex == columnToCheck)
        {
            using (var DB = new DataContext())
            {
                if (DB.YourTable.Where(v => v.id == dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()).Count > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "";
                    MessageBox.Show("This key already exists");
                    //Return the error message to your javascript in asp.net here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In a website however, you'd have to make an ajax call, so whichever datatable you're using, find its event which would similar to dataGridView's CellValueChanged event. If you fail to do so, try adding the onchanged="" tag to its HTML element definition e.g. `<table class="table" id="tab" onchanged="eventfunction(this)"></table>` and in your javascript, handle the call like the following:

```
function eventfunction(element)
{
    //Use an ajax call to your controller from here
    var id = document.getElementById(element.id).innerText; //or however you can obtain the active cells' value
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/ControllerName/ActionName",
        method: "POST",
        data: id,
        success: function (response)
            {
                //Handle the return call here
            },
        error: function (response)
            {
                //Or here if you return an error message
            }
        });
}
```

Or you can use jQuery's event handling like this:

```
$("#tab").on("onchange", function()
{
    //Your code here
});
```

You controller can look like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Customer GetCustomer(string id)
    {
       //LINQ Where validation here
    }
```